# How can I access a class which is a member of another class?

Tags: vb6

Please note that this is VB6!
I have a class named Kostenvoranschlag.
It has a member array of a class named Positionen.

I have declared it as such

```
Class Kostenvoranschlag

    Private m_Positionen() As position

    Public Function Positionen() As position

         Positionen = m_Positionen

    End Function 

End Class

Class Position
  
    Public Betrag As Currency

End Class
```

The following does not compile and throws "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property".

```
Dim k As New kv
kv.Positionen(0).Betrag = 5
```

How can I access this class from outside?

ps: I have also tried these 2 versions, but they wouldn't compile either:

```
Friend Function Positionen() As position

     Positionen = m_Positionen

End Function 

Public Property Get Positionen() As position()
    Positionen = m_Positionen
End Property
```

Comment: Have you tried making `m_Positionen()` public? I.e. use a public field that is an array.

Comment: I think your `Positionen()` function is returning one single `position`, not an array. The parentheses after `Positionen` just mean the function doesn't take any arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the question, when using an array of classes the following syntax does not work for whatever reason:

```
k.Positionen(0).Betrag = 5
```

But this syntax DOES work:

```
Dim p() As Position
p = k.Positionen
p(0).Betrag = 5
```

However, I would typically set this up using collections instead of arrays.  If you do this, then the single line syntax works.

Comment: In VB.NET, it does work. So I don't know what to say about that.... Thanks for the idea of the collection.

Comment: @tmighty VB.net is not the same language, they made plenty of syntax changes when they created it after VB6 was abandoned.